# Cycling through images in wx.StaticBitmap

Tags: wxpython

I'm working on a database of images and want to display each image as it is processed in a wx.StaticBitmap object. As far as I can understand, the line in the function onView, "self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(self.img))" should change the image. But nothing I do will get it to display. The code is from my explorations into an answer and is part of an image display app that changes the image on each click of the button. This works perfectly but as soon as the code is embedded in the loop it fails to refresh until the loop is complete where the last of the files finally displays.

```py
    import time
    import os
    import wx

    #============ App and panel class ========#
    class PhotoCtrl(wx.App):
        def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
            wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
            self.frame = wx.Frame(None, title='Photo Control')

            self.panel = wx.Panel(self.frame)

            self.PhotoMaxSize = 256

            self.createWidgets()
            self.frame.Show()

    #=========== Set up button, wx.StaticBitmap etc ===============#

        def createWidgets(self):
            #instructions = 'Browse for an image'
            img = wx.Image(256,256)
            self.imageCtrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(img))
            browseBtn = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Go')
            browseBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onView)

            self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

            self.mainSizer.Add(wx.StaticLine(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY),
                               0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
            #self.mainSizer.Add(instructLbl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
            self.mainSizer.Add(self.imageCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
            #self.sizer.Add(self.photoTxt, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
            self.sizer.Add(browseBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)        
            self.mainSizer.Add(self.sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

            self.panel.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
            self.mainSizer.Fit(self.frame)

            self.panel.Layout()

    #=== Toy code to simulate automatic change of image to be displayed ===#

        def onView(self, event):
            for i in range(1,10):
                im_pth = os.getcwd() + f'/Cats/cats/Cats_{i}.png'
                self.img = wx.Image(im_pth, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
                self.image = self.img.ConvertToImage()
                self.img = wx.Bitmap(self.image.Scale(256, 256))
                self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(self.img))
                self.panel.Refresh()
                print(f"should be showing cat_{i}") #This prints but the image doesn't show
                time.sleep(1)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = PhotoCtrl()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are in a loop, which does not release control back to the `mainloop`.
You need to `Yield` before `time.sleep(1)`

i.e.

```
def onView(self, event):
    for i in range(1,10):
        im_pth = os.getcwd() + f'/frame{i}.png'
        self.img = wx.Image(im_pth, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.image = self.img.ConvertToImage()
        self.img = wx.Bitmap(self.image.Scale(256, 256))
        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(self.img))
        self.panel.Refresh()
        wx.Yield()
        print(f"should be showing cat_{i}") #This prints but the image doesn't show
        time.sleep(1)
```

Strictly speaking, under wxPython Phoenix that should be `wx.GetApp().Yield()` but `wx.Yield()` still works.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that fixes it, although there is a slight assumption there. I fixed my immediate problem by ditching wx.Bitmap and using a matplotlib canvas instead, which updates nicely. But then I was having trouble getting my TextCtrl to update and adding wx.Yield() to the TextAppend function has it working perfectly. With that caveat I'm happy to accept the answer, thanks again.

Comment: There is no assumption. I used your code, as posted. Your use of `matplotlib` ensures that `matplotlib` controls the drawing of the image.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the assumption is mine, not yours. As I'd moved on with matplotlib I didn't go back and test the answer myself for the image.

Comment: No problem, although putting ´matplotlib` in there vs a `Yield` is probably not very efficient. It may not be important for your project.